# What other code is needed to get the photos from Instagram's API to show up?

Tags: objective-c, instagram-api

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to create a photo app for my iOS development class that displays users pics based on a specific hashtag, but I am not having any luck. I have the API for Instagram along with my client_id. When I run it, there aren't any errors but the screen is just black. What else is needed for me to get the images showing up? This is what i have so far. Thanks in advance!

```
@interface ViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

@property NSMutableArray *picFeed;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/chicago/media/recent?count=100&client_id=d3eed38ae896497e9e58298dd793333b"];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, 
NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        self.picFeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&connectionError];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.picFeed.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Try tag your post with what language you are coding in (not just instagram) so the right users can help you. Also select all your code and then press CTRL + K to get that code section you see on other posts to make this clearer.

Comment: You need to put your `self.picFeed` objects into an imageView in your CollectionViewCell. They don't just show up on there own. You're getting the data properly but not making it appear anywhere